# How to move images up in 3d plane

Tags: javascript, css

I want to move images up in the plane.

[See image for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jow7y.jpg)

In the image you can see lines are drawn in a 3-d plane. I want to show flying drone above the lines. Consider those lines as a path for drone in air. I want to show the drone is flying on those path in the air.

My question is not how can i move drone on surface, i can do it easily. Drones are moving very well on the surface. I want to move the drone in air.

#### Main question

Drone is an image.

How can i give a z-offset to the image so it will looks like in air.
Any library or shadows or anyhow we can do?

Comment: No matter how much z-offset you provide, it is still on 2D display. you have to draw in such a way to give it 3D perspective.  You can start from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective or use any JavaScript 3D library.

Comment: I am going to view `perspective` as you said.

Comment: > use any JavaScript 3D library   ..   ... Is this can be done with **threejs**

Comment: yes, any 3D library which you are aware of or comfortable with.

Comment: if you want something like this http://snapsvg.io/demos/#globe have a look at snapsvg, also if you want some real 3d thing have a look at https://cesium.com/docs/tutorials/build-a-flight-tracker/

Comment: Adding cesium is not good for a small things.